# Terminal will not launch and stay open

Tags: command-line, login, power-management, gnome-terminal, tty

I went over to my Ubuntu machine and noticed a blank screen. I ended up having to, after careful diagnosis, force reboot. Everything loaded up like it should, but when I logged in terminal wouldn't open and STAY open. If I click on it, it just opens for a split second and closes.

After rebooting again and doing everything I could think of, I tried opening text to terminal (ctrl+alt+F1) When trying to login, it flashed quickly again, saying a few things so fast I couldn't read them. I tried logging in again to text to terminal and this time I captured it on my iPhone slo mo cam. It said the usual stuff about last login, documentation and blah blah blah.

However, what is unusual is it says, `Shell access is disabled` and then goes back to (Computer Name) login:. So my question is. How do I get terminal back open and stay open without wiping this computer again?

I say again because the last time this exact thing happened, I was in a rush so I just performed a fresh clean install. However this keeps happening, and I can't do that every time. One other thing though: this computer probably was running a terminal process, one that I didn't finish, when it probably lost power. This was the result of the "blank" screen. I hope someone can help with this mess.

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your user's shell has been set to something like `/bin/false`. If this is the case, here's one way to tell.

If you look in your `/etc/passwd` file, find the line with your username on it and examine the final argument (The text after the last `:`) this describes the path to your user's shell.

Typically this is set with the command `chsh`, but since you can't use the command line, try editing the `/etc/passwd` file as root and set the shell to `/bin/bash`

i.e. a line like this:

`username:x:1001:1002::/home/username:/bin/false`

would become

`username:x:1001:1002::/home/username:/bin/bash`

Now save the file, logout and log back in.

Comment: Ok, so how do I edit this without terminal in my back pocket? It is obviously owned by root. sudo, oh how I miss you.

Comment: If you did see your shell was set to `/bin/false`
I have this suggestion, first, install `gksu`, if you can't find it in ubuntu software center, then install synaptic, and use synaptic to install `gksu`

Second alt + F2 will let you type a command in, enter `gksudo gedit /etc/passwd`

Comment: Alternatively, create a new administrative user with the control panel, it may have shell access enabled.

Comment: So was it the gksudo or the new user that got you there?

Comment: gksudo was the easiest! I feel like such an idiot!

Comment: The thing that messed it up was mysecureshell. It said /bin/mysecureshell. WOW... I need a separate user for that I guess.